# how to implement search query for multiple record seperated by comma from single field single column?

Tags: php, sql, ajax

```
if(count($_POST["search"]) > 0) {

     $arrayString =  implode("','",$_POST["search"]) ;
}
//echo $arrayString;exit;

 $sql="SELECT * FROM domain_inventory_Global_History WHERE company_domain in ('$arrayString') ";
 echo $sql;
```

Comment: www.google.com,www.santosh.com         suppose these tworecords are in single field column ,i have taken it in to array string variable ,how to fire query for this recoed

Comment: you may use LIKE operator to handle this .Forexample  `$sql="SELECT * FROM domain_inventory_Global_History WHERE company_domain LIKE %$arrayString % "`

Comment: Use `LIKE txt`, `LIKE %txt` and `LIKE txt%`

Answer (score 0):

you may use LIKE operator to handle this .Forexample

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM domain_inventory_Global_History WHERE company_domain LIKE %$arrayString%"
```

Comment: Okk try this  `$sql="SELECT * FROM domain_inventory_Global_History WHERE company_domain LIKE %".$arrayString."%"`

Answer (score 0):

$searchStrings = ['google.com','yahoo','fa'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM domain_inventory_Global_History WHERE where company_domain like %".implode("% or company_domain like %",$searchStrings)."%";

echo $sql;

Comment: please provide some explanation and format properly your answer